# VMs in separate subnet can ping each other

Tags: azure, networking

In Azure, I have 2 VMs, each in their own subnet (see image below). To my surprise, both VMs can "see" each other (using ping).

The subnet address ranges are:

- net1-subnet1: 10.0.1.0/24
- net1-subnet2: 10.0.2.0/24

The VMs (NIC) IPs are:

- vm1: 10.0.1.4
- vm2: 10.0.2.4

This is the setup
[image]

Why are both VMs able to ping each other? I thought since they are in different subnets, they would not be able to "see" each other. Is this an Azure specific feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure routes traffic between subnets in the same virtual network (or peered virtual networks) by default as described in the [Azure virtual networks overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview#route-network-traffic).

You can use network security groups to filter traffic flowing in- and outbound to/from these subnets. The default rules will allow traffic from a virtual network, so you will have to add some of your own rules with a higher priority to the Network Security Groups (NSG). See docs in NSG [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview#network-security-groups)